# How can I revert the buffer at point in emacs' buffer list?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to create a function that will revert buffers from emacs' `*Buffer List*` buffer. As far as I can tell from the documentation, there's no way to do this quickly (in the manner of the save/mark/visit functions built in to `buff-menu.el`). So I'm writing some elisp. Here's my current attempt:

```
(defun frobnitz ()
  "Call in buffer list to revert buffer at point to file."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (buffer-menu-buffer t)))
    (if (y-or-n-p (concat "Revert " (buffer-name (buf)) " ?"))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (let (())
        (revert-buffer t t t)
        (message
          (concat "Reverted " (buffer-name (buf)) "to last saved state."))
        )))))
```

Unfortunately, the above defun doesn't seem to work, and I'm having trouble figuring out why. If I eval the above, switch to the `*Buffer List*` buffer, and invoke <kbd>M-: (frobnitz)</kbd>, then it errors out with the following.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function buffer-menu-buffer)
  (buffer-menu-buffer t)
  (let ((buf (buffer-menu-buffer t))) (if (y-or-n-p (concat "Revert " (buffer-name (buf)) " ?")) (with-current-buffer buf (let (nil) (revert-buffer t t t) (message (concat "Reverted " (buffer-name (buf)) "to last saved state."))))))
  frobnitz()
  eval((frobnitz) nil)
  eval-expression((frobnitz) nil)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
```

It seems like that's telling me that there's no function `buffer-menu-buffer` - but that also seems gratuitously unlikely, since `buffer-menu-buffer` is a pretty central function in getting the buffer menu to work! For similar reasons, I'm deeply wary of messing with `buffer-menu-buffer` myself - I don't want to break the buffer menu.

Bearing in mind that the answer might be "invoke this function that you overlooked," how can I get this defun to accomplish its stated purpose of reverting a buffer directly from the buffer menu?

---

**Update:** as answerer Sean points out, the correct name of the function I was having a hard time with is `Buffer-menu-buffer` with a capital initial B. Having fixed that problem, I came across another:

```
  (let (nil) (revert-buffer t t t) (message (concat "Reverted " buf-name "to last saved state.")))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (let (nil) (revert-buffer t t t) (message (concat "Reverted " buf-name "to last saved state."))))
  (with-current-buffer buf (let (nil) (revert-buffer t t t) (message (concat "Reverted " buf-name "to last saved state."))))
  (if (y-or-n-p (concat "Revert " buf-name " ?")) (with-current-buffer buf (let (nil) (revert-buffer t t t) (message (concat "Reverted " buf-name "to last saved state.")))))
  (let ((buf (Buffer-menu-buffer t)) (buf-name (concat "" (buffer-name (Buffer-menu-buffer t))))) (if (y-or-n-p (concat "Revert " buf-name " ?")) (with-current-buffer buf (let (nil) (revert-buffer t t t) (message (concat "Reverted " buf-name "to last saved state."))))))
  frobnitz()
  eval((frobnitz) nil)
  eval-expression((frobnitz) nil)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
```

My guess is that `with-current-buffer` tries to save the current buffer and that's a no-no on `*Buffer List*`. So now I'm looking for an alternative - maybe just switch, revert, and invoke `(buffer-list)` to switch back.

---

**Update 2:**

For future readers: The working function and a single-key binding to invoke it in `buffer-menu-mode`:

```
;; Enhance the buffer menu's capabilities.
(defun revert-buffer-from-buffer-list ()
  "Call in buffer list to revert buffer at point to file.

Bind this to a key in `buffer-menu-mode' to use it there - not productive in
other modes because it depends on the `Buffer-menu-buffer' function. Undefined
behavior if you invoke it on a buffer not associated with a file: that's why it
has a confirmation gate. Buffers not associated with files get to play by their
own rules when it comes to `revert-buffer' (which see)."
  (interactive)
  (let (
        (buf (Buffer-menu-buffer t))
        (buf-name (concat "" (buffer-name(Buffer-menu-buffer t))))
        )
    (if (y-or-n-p (concat "Revert " buf-name " ?"))
        (with-current-buffer buf
          (let ()
            (revert-buffer t t t)
            (message (concat "Reverted " buf-name " to last saved state."))
            )))))
(add-hook 'Buffer-menu-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key Buffer-menu-mode-map (kbd "R") revert-buffer-from-buffer-list)
            ))
```

Also an exhortation to caution: `add-hook` is not idempotent, so if you add things to `foo-mode-hook` that you don't intend to or which don't work, you risk breaking `foo-mode` until you zorch `foo-mode-hook` or prune the broken elements out of it. Ask me how I know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Emacs has a function `Buffer-menu-buffer`, but no `buffer-menu-buffer`.  I imagine that's what's tripping you up.

EDIT:

I found two more problems with your code, after which I was able to revert buffers from the buffer menu with it.

- I had to change `(buf)` to `buf` in two places.  `buf` is a variable, not a function to call.
- The `(let (()) ...)` construct causes an error.  Either eliminate it, or change it to `(let () ...)` (although I don't know why you'd want to).

Comment: That was definitely a problem, thanks - I was getting that wrong. And now a different issue - want to take a try at round 2?

Comment: I independently realized the part about variable vs. function, but the issue with `let ()` wasn't on my radar at all. Thanks for clearing that up. Function works correctly now, accepting. :)